# Select columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, database, union

Fairly new in mySQL and I got a question to query values from different tables and I guess to also eliminate duplicates. I tried UNION

```
SELECT emp_name FROM employee
UNION
SELECT branch_name, floor FROM branch;
```

but it said error: "#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

The question is: List branch_name, floor and emp_name who work in the branches.

The tables are

EMPLOYEE

> emp_no (PK), emp_name, branch_no

BRANCH

> branch_no (PK), branch_name, floor

Comment: Hint, try Join and upload your query

Comment: @nacho I tried it and it worked! Thank you


```
SELECT branch.Branch_Name, branch.Floor, employee.Emp_Name FROM branch INNER JOIN employee ON employee.branch_no=branch.branch_no;
```


not sure about the final line, but is that how I should do it? Anyway, it output the answer that I needed, so I guess it is right? Thanks again

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Your explanation is not 100% clear [to me].

Comment: I am glad it helped you better than telling just the answer, so you can learn. That query looks ok